# How to make restart right?

Tags: python, pygame

I created game state variable to my game can restart when I use necessary buttons. I made function main(), but my game slows down very strongly and I don't know what to do. What have I to do to my game will work correctly and my game can restart?

```
game_state = 'beginning'
def start_game():
    global game_state
    game_state = 'game1'
def pause_game():
    global game_state
    game_state = 'pause'
def game_over():
    global game_state
    game_state = 'game_over'
def quit_game():
    global game_state
    game_state = 'quit'
def main():
    global game_state
    while game_state != pygame.QUIT:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        event_list = pygame.event.get() 
        for event in event_list:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                QuitState.set_quit()
            if game_state == 'beginning':
                for event in event_list:
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        QuitState.set_quit() 
                mini_button = Button(230, 80)
                screen.blit(important_phone_jpg, important_phone_rect)
                print_text_5('Выживание с Соником', 320, 50)
                mini_button.draw(535, 170, 'Играть', start_game)
                mini_button1 = Button(440, 80)
                pygame.display.update()
            elif game_state == 'game1':
                #[...]
                while event in event_list:
                    clock.tick(FPS)
                    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
                        if event.type == KEYDOWN:    
                            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                                player.jump()
                                pygame.mixer.Sound.play(jump_sound)
                        #[...]
                        elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                            QuitState.set_quit()  
                    #[...]
                    if player.score >= 900:
                        pygame.mixer.Sound.play(win_sound)
                        victory1()
                    if health <= 0:
                        game_over1()
                    show_health()
                    button = Button(195,80)
                    button.draw(20, 80, 'Пауза', pause_game)
                    print_text('Очки  ' + str(player.score), 725, 25)
                    print_text(':', 840, 25)
                    pygame.display.update()
                    all_sprites.update()
                    screen.blit(morning_png, morning_rect)
                    all_sprites.draw(screen)
            elif game_state == 'pause':
                while not QuitState.quit:
                    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                    clock.tick(FPS)
                    for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                            QuitState.set_quit()  
                    screen.blit(phone_jpg, phone_rect)
                    buttonq = Button(120, 80)
                    print_text_2('Хотите продолжить игру?', 400, 270)
                    buttonq.draw(300, 340, 'Да!', start_game)
                    buttonq_1 = Button(140, 80)
                    buttonq_1.draw(870, 340, 'Нет!', beginning)
                    pygame.display.update()
            elif game_over1():
                pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                while not QuitState.quit:
                    clock.tick(FPS)
                    for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                            QuitState.set_quit() 
                    screen.blit(game_over_jpg, game_over_rect)
                    button_5 = Button(235,80)
                    print_text_3('К сожалению, вы проиграли! Попробуйте ещё раз!', 135, 400)
                    button_5.draw(400, 500, 'Заново', start_game)
                    button_5.draw(700, 500, 'Назад', beginning)
                    pygame.display.update()
main()
```

Also my program shows error:
NameError: name 'beginning' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

```
            while not QuitState.quit:
                clock.tick(FPS)
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        QuitState.set_quit() 
                screen.blit(game_over_jpg, game_over_rect)
                button_5 = Button(235,80)
                print_text_3('К сожалению, вы проиграли! Попробуйте ещё раз!', 135, 400)
                button_5.draw(400, 500, 'Заново', start_game)
                button_5.draw(700, 500, 'Назад', beginning)
                pygame.display.update()
```

This is likely creating and drawing a button every iteration and filling your ran memory. As the new button is being drawn on top of the old one you are not noticing. This is happening in various parts of your code. Create the button outside the loop and just draw inside the loop. A tip: try to have only one while loop for your whole game, this will make the code easier to understand.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).